# Porting development environment from Visual Studio 2003 to 2010: why am I getting LNK2005 errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, linker, visual-studio-2003

I currently have two DLL libraries - CMN and GT. GT is dependent on CMN.

In Visual Studio 2003, I can compile and link both libraries without issue. I can compile CMN and GT successfully in Visual Studio 2010, and link CMN. If I try to link GT however, I get the following errors:

```
CMN.lib(CMN.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in TokenizerAdvanced.obj
CMN.lib(CMN.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in TokenizerAdvanced.obj
CMN.lib(CMN.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) already defined in TokenizerAdvanced.obj
CMN.lib(CMN.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned int)" (?reserve@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEXI@Z) already defined in TokenizerAdvanced.obj
CMN.lib(CMN.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::erase(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?erase@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV12@II@Z) already defined in TokenizerAdvanced.obj
```

TokenizerAdvanced is a source file in GT.

All compiling and linking is done with the same command-line structure (using -MDd to compile). What has changed between Visual Studio 2003 and 2010 that would cause this issue?

**Edit:** Strangely enough, if I exclude TokenizerAdvanced.cpp from the build (the other file - Tokenizer.cpp does not reference it), I get an unresolved external error:

```
Tokenizer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int const std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::npos" (?npos@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@2IB)
```

**Edit:** Moved investigation into answer.

Comment: do you use the same runtime libraries? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#Issues

Comment: That can be a unicode - nonunicode mangling issue. Can you check if both of these libraries have the same character set?

Comment: Yes. I've used (essentially) the same command line for both. The environment should be the only major difference when building.

Comment: See `TokenizerAdvanced` file; try to comment it out (completely or partially) and see what happens. Do you use some static runtime libraries in your dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the problem. We have classes that derive from string in CMN. See [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/562448/std-string-npos-lnk2001-when-inheriting-a-dll-class-from-std-string).

[This discussion](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586959/std) suggests adding the following to the client library source code:

```
template std::string::size_type std::string::npos;
template std::wstring::size_type std::wstring::npos;
```

But this didn't solve the problem for me.

[This discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/13e8a822-dd48-41ba-bca8-9bbd3163f6c4) suggests changing any classes that derive from string (and I have noticed that our code does so in a few places) to use containment instead, which is what I ended up doing. This fixed the issue.